# I'm removing characters from a range of cells. How do I stop it looping?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm trying to automate a few processes I regularly complete as a way of learning VBA. I'm writing a code that selects all cells in the worksheet and removes a certain character anywhere is occurs. In my case, I'm removing double spaces from strings.

The code I'm using does the job and removes the double spaces but it continues to loop for what seems like an indefinite amount of time.

```
Dim celref As String

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

    For Each c In Range(Selection, ActiveCell)
    celref = c.Value
           Do While InStr(1, celref, "  ")
           Selection.Replace What:="  ", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
        Loop
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not trying to preserve leading/trailing spaces, you could do something like:

```
c.Value = application.trim(c.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `.Select` statements, they're triggering unneeded processes.

```
For Each c In Range("A1", SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Cells
    With c
        While InStr(.Value, "  "): .Value = Replace(.Value, "  ", " "): Wend
    End With
Next
```

---

***Edit:*** *Just noticed Rory's answer, much more efficient and quicker. I'll leave this here as an example.*

Answer (score 0):

This is great, works perfectly.

```
Sub Removestuff()

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

       For Each c In Range(Selection, ActiveCell)
    c.Value = Application.Trim(c.Value)
    Next c

End Sub
```